# Defining which branch my next commit is added to

Tags: mercurial, branch

Let's say I create two banches ***at the same time***:

```
hg branch branch-A
hg branch branch-B
```

How do I send my next commit to **branch-A** instead of **branch-B**?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`hg branch X` does **nothing** except tell Mercurial "the next commit I make should be on branch X."  It doesn't actually "create" the branch.  A branch doesn't exist until there's at least one commit on it:

```
sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on default at tip
$ hg branch a
marked working directory as branch a

sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on a at tip
$ hg branch b
marked working directory as branch b

sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on b at tip
$ hg branches
default                        0:aae011bc1b00

sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on b at tip
$ echo foo >> x

sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on b at tip!
$ hg com -m1

sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on b at tip
$ hg branches
b                              1:b66106035d8d
default                        0:aae011bc1b00 (inactive)

sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on b at tip
$
```

So the answer to your question is: "use `hg branch branch-A` to mark the next commit as being on branch-A."

Comment: Great info, but might be worth adding the way to do what OP is trying to do: hg branch branchA; commit to branchA; hg update default; hg branch branchB, commit to branchB. The key is "hg update default", so branchB is based on the same commit as branchA.

Comment: Good info, bad explanation. sjl at ecgtheow.. Eh..? also hg com, make this hg commit for Googlers. People should not need to Decipher answers. Sorry, but -1.

Comment: Hi Steve, why don't you add this info on your guide in a more explicit way than it is now? Might improve the guide. ("hg branch X does nothing except tell Mercurial "the next commit I make should be on branch X." It doesn't actually "create" the branch. A branch doesn't exist until there's at least one commit on it")

Answer (score 0):

As Carl Meyer says I'd go for:

```
hg branch branch-A
commit branch-A
hg update default
hg branch branch-B
commit branch-B
```

Ironically, I think Steve Losh provides a better answer on his guide then here (though "A branch doesn't exist until there's at least one commit on it" is a very good tip that I'd add in the guide).

If you read the [section on named branches](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-named-branches), he gives a concise explanation on how they work and how to switch between them.

Answer (score -5):

Use '`hg update -C branch-name`'.

Comment: No.  If the branch commands happen one after another the first branch won't exist because there are no commits on it.  Also, blindly using -C with update is not a good idea.  It's much safer to use -c normally and only use -C when you really need it.